# Custom Menu for bpy.context

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I am working on making a custom menu that would allow access to things like Cycle Render, Blender Render, changing file formats for render outputs, etc.

I understand how to make menus using operators like

`layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="Add as Active"). type = 'ACTIVE'`

Is the process for creating menus for `bpy.context.scene` similar or am I missing some basic understanding of python and how Blender works?

UPDATE....

In the info panel I am trying to execute this.

```
 bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
```

I am using this template from cgcookie.

EXAMPLE

```
import bpy

# Creates a menu for global 3D View
class customMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Sub"
    bl_idname = "view3D.sub"

    # Set the menu operators and draw functions
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="A Add Active").type = 'ACTIVE'
        layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="B Add Passive").type = 'PASSIVE'
      # here is were I would like to add a menu item to change to cycles.

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(customMenu)
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=customMenu.bl_idname)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(customMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: care to show a mock-up it's difficult to be confident about what the question is, or the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You want to have a look at the [`ops.wm.context_...`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.context_collection_boolean_set) family of operators, which are 'generic' operators that can be used to define a value (or cycle through a set of values) of any compatible property accessible through context. This avoid the need to define a custom operator.

E.g. for an enum property like `context.scene.render.engine`:

```
import bpy

# Creates a menu for global 3D View
class customMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Sub"
    bl_idname = "view3D.sub"

    # Set the menu operators and draw functions
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="A Add Active").type = 'ACTIVE'
        layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="B Add Passive").type = 'PASSIVE'
        op = layout.operator("wm.context_set_enum", text="Set Cycles Renderer")
        op.data_path = "scene.render.engine"
        op.value = 'CYCLES'


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(customMenu)
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=customMenu.bl_idname)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(customMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note that you can also use `layout.prop()` and the like, just like in a regular panel - but beware, most of our widgets are not really designed nor tested in menus… Afaik in 'official' UI we only do that for some boolean properties (giving small toggle boxes in the menus). Seems to work rather well with enums, though, producing a sub-menu:

```
import bpy

# Creates a menu for global 3D View
class customMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Sub"
    bl_idname = "view3D.sub"

    # Set the menu operators and draw functions
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="A Add Active").type = 'ACTIVE'
        layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="B Add Passive").type = 'PASSIVE'
        layout.prop(context.scene.render, "engine")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(customMenu)
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=customMenu.bl_idname)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(customMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: In the info panel I am trying to execute this.  "bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
import bpy
class customMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Sub"
    bl_idname = "view3D.sub"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
   layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="A Add Active").type = 'ACTIVE'
            layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_add", text="B Add Passive").type = 'PASSIVE'
            layout.operator("rigidbody.objects_remove", text="C Remove from Rigid")
            # add this
            layout.context("scene.render").engine = 'CYCLES'

Comment: @Mark Please edit your question rather than adding precisions in comments, this is not even readable. Also, assuming you are doing this in draw code, you will not be allowed to *change* anything (any data) in such part of the code…